# Node.js on port 80

Tags: apache, node.js

I have an application in Node.js that runs on port 3010 (domain.com:3010). Is it possible to make it run on port 80 (domain.com) ?

I have a VPS server with CentOS.
I searched a lot but nothing has worked.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the app?

Comment: Yes I have, but I can't change to port 80 because it's used by Apache

Comment: Then have Apache redirect requests to 80 to 3010. You definitely can't have several servers listening on the same port!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual host as described on [this article](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName node.mydomain.com
    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3010/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3010/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hey!, this is awesome I got it working in 5 mins, but the POST request doesn't work, is this only for GET or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's better to use Nginx instead of Apache in front of Node.js. 
Configuration example (my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file)

```
    upstream my-node-app {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #server_name  _;
        server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;


        access_log  /var/log/nginx.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the port in the app configurations or configure the ports to respond as you want in your router.